# Does apple iTunesConnect allow landscape only App with portrait screen shot in iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

we have created iPhone game with landscape only mode, but screenShot our designer created are in portrait mode. Does apple iTunes connect allow this ?

Comment: Simply. Yes they can approve your app.

Comment: Why dont you change them ? Apple  can do anything ;)

Comment: @The Tiger,  designer already made some work...so wish to know if anyone experimented in this area.

Comment: @iHungry, Is that 100% true? if yes then we can go ahead with same approach.

Comment: They will not reject your app cause of this issue ... but can't take 100% guarantee.

Comment: It happened to me once. At the time of creating app in iTunes account I had uploaded dummy Icon and Screenshot images. After uploading binary I was expecting I will get a chance to make changes but It went directly to the appstore and I removed it later. :)

Comment: @iHungry you are correct..apple approve. here is one other app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metal-storm-cat/id591320116?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

Your app won't get rejected if the images share the same content in pics and in the app. The orientation of the pics is irrelevant as long as everything else ok by apple. Worst case scenario (which I very much doubt) they will ask you to upload new pics.

Comment: see this app, landscape app with portrait screenshot: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metal-storm-cat/id591320116?mt=8